# i do not understand error expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

Tags: c

I don't get what is wrong with my code. Please help
me. I'm a beginner.

Errors like "expected primary expression before 'int'. Expected constructor, destructor, or type of conversion before '(' token. Expected '}' before int. Expected ',' or ';' before int.

As well as 'av' does not name a type. Expected unqualified-id before if.

I don't understand.

```
int main{
    int q=0, qu=0, qui=0, mid=0, fe=0;
    float av=0, fg=0;

    printf("\nEnter Quiz 1:");
    scanf("%d", &q);
    printf("\nEnter Quiz 2:");
    scanf("%d", &qu);
    printf("\nEnter Quiz 3:");
    scanf("%d", &qui);
    
    av = ((q+qu+qui)/3)*10;
    
    printf("\nEnter Midterm Score:");
    scanf("%d",&mid);
    printf("\nEnter Final Exam Score:");
    scanf("%d",&fe);
    
    fg = 0.5*fe + 0.25*mid +0.25*qav;
    
    scanf("%f",&fg);
    
    if ((fg>=90) && (fg<=100))          
        printf("A\n");
        
    else 
    if ((fg>=80) && (fg<90))
        printf("B\n");
    
    else 
    if ((fg>=70) && (fg<80))
        printf("C\n");
    
    else 
    if ((fg>=60) && (fg<70))
        printf("D\n");
        
    else
        printf("\nF");
}
```

Comment: This is C not C++, retagged.

Comment: The code looks like plain C but the error message sounds like you run it in a C++ compiler.

Comment: Just define the variables separately, like int a=0; int b=0; etc.. mind the ; to separate statements, commas are only useful in for-loops, argument lists, template definitions..

Comment: '((q+qu+qui)/3)*10;' did you intend integer division and, if so, why is the division performed before the mult by 10?  Did you intend to lose accuracy?

Answer (score 2):

```
int main{
```

should be

```
int main(){
```

Function definitions (like `main`) need brackets which is where you put the list of parameters. In your code `main` doesn't have any parameters but you still need the brackets.

BTW this code seems wrong

```
fg = 0.5*fe + 0.25*mid +0.25*qav;

scanf("%f",&fg);
```

First you calculate `fg` and then you ask the user to input a value for `fg`. That doesn't make any sense. I think you should delete `scanf("%f",&fg);`.